# Cabal compiles code twice

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I run `cabal build`, cabal goes through the process of compiling twice. Since compiling takes relatively long time already (~60 seconds), this is starting to impede my workflow.

Here is the ghc options in my cabal file:

```
GHC-Options: -O3 -rtsopts -funbox-strict-fields -threaded -Wall -feager-blackholing -fllvm -optlo-O3
if flag(Eventlog)
  GHC-Options: -O3 -rtsopts -funbox-strict-fields -threaded -eventlog -Wall
if flag(Profiling)
  ghc-prof-options: -O3 -auto-all
  GHC-Options: -O3 -rtsopts -funbox-strict-fields -threaded -fprof-auto -Wall
if flag(Dump)
  GHC-options: -O3 -funbox-strict-fields -Wall -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-module-prefixes -dsuppress-uniques -ddump-to-file
```

The output from `cabal build` looks completely normal except the compilation restarts as soon as the last module finishes compiling the first time.

```
[ 1 of 13] Compiling HaObj            ( src/HaObj.hs, nothing )
[ 2 of 13] Compiling Surfaces         ( src/Surfaces.hs, nothing )
[ 3 of 13] Compiling Materials        ( src/Materials.hs, nothing )
[ 4 of 13] Compiling Geometry3        ( src/Geometry3.hs, nothing )
[ 5 of 13] Compiling Triangles        ( src/Triangles.hs, nothing )
[ 6 of 13] Compiling BoundingVolumeHierarchy ( src/BoundingVolumeHierarchy.hs, nothing )
[ 7 of 13] Compiling RayTracer        ( src/RayTracer.hs, nothing )
[ 8 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene5  ( src/BenchmarkScene5.hs, nothing )
[ 9 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene4  ( src/BenchmarkScene4.hs, nothing )
[10 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene3  ( src/BenchmarkScene3.hs, nothing )
[11 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene2  ( src/BenchmarkScene2.hs, nothing )
[12 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene   ( src/BenchmarkScene.hs, nothing )
[13 of 13] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, nothing )
[ 1 of 13] Compiling HaObj            ( src/HaObj.hs, nothing )
[ 2 of 13] Compiling Surfaces         ( src/Surfaces.hs, nothing )
[ 3 of 13] Compiling Materials        ( src/Materials.hs, nothing )
[ 4 of 13] Compiling Geometry3        ( src/Geometry3.hs, nothing )
[ 5 of 13] Compiling Triangles        ( src/Triangles.hs, nothing )
[ 6 of 13] Compiling BoundingVolumeHierarchy ( src/BoundingVolumeHierarchy.hs, nothing )
[ 7 of 13] Compiling RayTracer        ( src/RayTracer.hs, nothing )
[ 8 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene5  ( src/BenchmarkScene5.hs, nothing )
[ 9 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene4  ( src/BenchmarkScene4.hs, nothing )
[10 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene3  ( src/BenchmarkScene3.hs, nothing )
[11 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene2  ( src/BenchmarkScene2.hs, nothing )
[12 of 13] Compiling BenchmarkScene   ( src/BenchmarkScene.hs, nothing )
[13 of 13] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, nothing )
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, GHC 7.10.1, cabal-install 1.22.4, cabal library 1.22.3. Here is a [link](https://github.com/jrraymond/ray-tracer) to the repo if you are interested in trying to reproduce. I would recommend running `cabal build --ghc-options="-fno-code"` to decrease build time to a couple of seconds.

EDIT: Zeta pointed out that is was because I have both an executable `ray-tracer` and a benchmark `bench` in my cabal file. Is there a way to build only one of them? I tried `cabal build ray-tracer` but this also built both targets. I also tried `cabal configure --disable-benchmarks`. Is there a way to selectively build only one of the targets without reorganizing the structure of the cabal file?

Comment: You probably have several targets, e.g. `executable` and `benchmark`. IIRC, cabal will build both by default. A quick look into your `.cabal` file reveals that this is most likely the culprit. You could create a library from your non-`Main.hs` files instead and have both the benchmark and the executable depend on it.

Comment: Why would you prefer your proposed solution, "build only one of them", to Zeta's proposed solution, "create a library and have both executables depend on it"?

Comment: IIRC, it's something along `cabal build exe:ray-tracer`. I can't check, still stuck at GHC 7.8.4.

Comment: Ok, now that I've tested it in GHC 7.10: this behaviour occurs __only__ if I use `-fno-code`, otherwise it gets compiled exactly once (both benchmark and executable). I suspect that `-fno-code` and `TemplateHaskell` aren't working completely hand in hand.

Comment: Well, with -fno-code it compiles fast enough that double compilation doesn't really matter too much. If @Zeta makes a answer with both of his solutions to the problem I will accept it.

Comment: @DanielWagner I guess because I would've thought that cabal should be able to do it.

Comment: @JustinRaymond That's not really an answer, though; even if cabal were able to do both (which it is), it seems like "build only one of them" is strictly inferior to "build the shared code once even when you build both artifacts" to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer from comments as community-wiki:

The syntax to build a single component is (for example) `cabal build exe:ray-tracer`